# Obtener registros de una hora específica todos los días Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Tengo un dataframe con Fecha como `index (aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)` con registros diarios y en diferentes horas del día, adjunto ejemplo, y requiero obtener todos los registros de todos los días pero únicamente de cierta hora, por ejemplo de 11 a 12 horas.

Dataframe de ejemplo:

```
      df.index,      cantidad
2017-01-01 09:58:26,    3
2017-01-01 10:20:45,    2
2017-01-01 11:00:01,    6
2017-01-01 11:01:20,    8
2017-01-01 11:34:12,    1
2017-01-01 12:09:32,    3
2017-01-02 09:58:26,    3
2017-01-02 10:20:45,    2
2017-01-02 11:00:01,    6
2017-01-02 11:01:20,    8
2017-01-02 11:34:12,    1
2017-01-02 12:09:32,    3
2017-01-03 09:58:26,    3
2017-01-03 10:20:45,    2
2017-01-03 11:00:01,    6
2017-01-03 11:01:20,    8
2017-01-03 11:34:12,    1
2017-01-03 12:09:32,    3
```

Entonces extraer los registros de todos los días que se encuentren únicamente entre las 11:00:00 y las 12:00:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenos días,

hacer esto con Pandas *es* muy directo. Tan sólo debes obtener el atributo `hora` de tu dataframe y hacer una máscara buscando los indíces que cumplen tus exigencias. Siguiendo tu ejemplo, sería tal que así:

```
df_resultado = df[(df.index.hour >= 11) & (df.index.hour <= 12)]
```

`df_resultado` es el dataframe que cumple con tus requisitos.

Comment: Gracias, si es lo que necesito.